# Is there a way to replace a character based off it's unicode code?

Tags: c#

I currently have a string which contains multiple characters. Certain characters need replacing with others based on their Unicode. For example '£' needs to become GBP. I have a Dictionary of the conversions like so.

```
Key = u00a3 Value = GBP
```

Currently I have this code but it trips up when it comes across characters that don't need any conversion (or aren't in the dictionary), for example an empty space remains as u0020.

```
var unicodeStringList = str.Select(t => $"u{Convert.ToUInt16(t):X4} ".ToLower()).ToList();
            str = string.Join("", unicodeStringList);

            foreach (var (key, value ) in characterSet)
            {
                str = str.Replace(key, value );
            }
            return str;
```

Is there any way I can just replace the characters without having to do any weird conversions, for example something that works like a string.replace?

```
    str = "£££";

    foreach (var (key, value ) in characterSet)
            {
                str = str.Replace(key, value );
            }/// expected output to be "GBPGBPGBP"
```

Comment: `str = str.Replace("\u00a3", "GBP");` works - are you missing the leading \?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up solving it like this:

```cs
            foreach (var (key, value ) in characterSet)
            {
                var hexValue = int.Parse(key.Substring(1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                str = str.Replace(((char)hexValue).ToString(), value );
            }
            return str;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can just replace the characters without having to do any weird conversions?

Not out of the box, but you can define one:

```
static string ToUnicode(this char c) => $"u{Convert.ToUInt16(t):X4}";
```

Then you just need to return the converted string if it is in the dictionary:

```
var replacedCharacters = str
    .Select(original => characterSet.TryGetValue(original.ToUnicode(), out var replaced)
        ? replaced
        : original.ToString());
```

And then concatenate them together:

```
str = string.Concat(replacedCharacters);
```

Comment: `original` is a `char` and `replaced` is a string. Does this even compile?

Comment: It doesn't compile for me

Comment: @Dialecticus Yeah, a `ToString()` is needed on the `char`.